# How make filter in ngx-pagination

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination

In Angular 7 + Electron 4 I use ngx-pagination but can't resolve problem with filter. 
 I make as in a [documentation](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/advanced), but I get error **Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'stringFilter' could not be found**
*Help me please. Thanks in advance*

Html-1:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="search"
  class="search__input"
  placeholder="Search by Name..."
  [(ngModel)]="tableService.filter">
```

Html-2:

```
<ul class="table-body__list">
 <li *ngFor="let item of tableService.items | stringFilter: tableService.filter | paginate: config">
   <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
 </li>
</ul>

<pagination-controls
  [maxSize]="maxSize"
  directionLinks="true"
  responsive="true"
  previousLabel="Previous page"
  nextLabel="Next page"
  (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)">        
</pagination-controls>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PaginationInstance } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { TableService } from '../../services/table.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobs-table',
  templateUrl: './jobs-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobs-table.component.scss']
})
export class JobsTableComponent implements OnInit {
  filter = '';
  maxSize = 9;
  config: PaginationInstance = {
    itemsPerPage: 11,
    currentPage: 1
  };

  constructor(public tableService: TableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onPageChange(number: number) {
    this.config.currentPage = number;
  }

}
```

In TableService:

```
filter = '';
```

Comment: what about trying with `filter` instead of  `stringFilter`. any better results?

Comment: You should create pipe `stringFilter`

Comment: ng g p stringFilter ?

Comment: `| filter: tableService.filter |` , `| tableService.filter |`, `| tableService.filter: filter |` all not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found on github (search on filter in the repository).  apparently npx-pagination doesn't come with any standard filter pipes.  their doc is .... sub-optimal

```
import {Pipe} from "@angular/core";

/**
 * A simple string filter, since Angular does not yet have a filter pipe built in.
 */
@Pipe({
    name: 'stringFilter'
})
export class StringFilterPipe {

    transform(value: string[], q: string) {
        if (!q || q === '') {
            return value;
        }
        return value.filter(item => -1 < item.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

Funny comment btw:  Angular removed pipes for filtering because of performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case I wrote code:
`
...
transform(itemList: Item[], searchStr: string): Item[] {
    if (itemList.length === 0 || searchStr === '') {
      return itemList;
    }
    return itemList.filter((item) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        item.employer.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

> you ca only change stringFilter with filter  .

```
<ul class="table-body__list">
 <li *ngFor="let item of tableService.items | filter: tableService.filter | paginate: config">
   <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
 </li>
</ul>
```